# Problem installing japanese language support on Xubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: xubuntu, language-support

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04.3 LTS on a virtualbox vm under windows 7. I'm now trying to install Japanese language support on it via command line, but it throws me this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 language-pack-ja : Depends: language-pack-ja-base (>= 1:14.04+20150804) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I googled that further, and then I found this supposedly temporary solution:
http://qiita.com/ariarijp/items/53a5eec3c30d767945c5

I applied that to `language-pack-gnome-ja` too (since the language support setting asked me to also install that), and then it works.

My question is, will I be alright with that old version of Japanese language support? Will it cause problems with other installed packages?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not cause any problems (besides possibly a few more untranslated strings).

I suspect that there is something wrong with the mirror server you are downloading packages from. You may want to open a terminal window, run the `software-properties-gtk` command, and switch to some other download server.

Comment: Tried that with the US repo instead of the usual local repo but it won't install. This time apt only tells me that it will install the mentioned language packages but then it stops there without actually installing them.

Comment: @tezman: You need to update after having switched server: `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Still does not work. I guess I'll make do with the old version. It still allows me to write normally after all.

Thank you for the answer and hints.